# Meteor Mongo, and Flow Router

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I recently started using MeteorJS (required for my job), and I'm having an issue with Meteor Mongo and Flow Router working together. When I load the page externally that fetches data from Mongo it returns empty, but if I go to the route through links internally on the application (after inserting stuff into Mongo) it doesn't return empty. I'm using auto publish, so I don't think it would be a subscription issue. Please help <3

```
FlowRouter.route('/assessment/:token/:admin', {
    action: function(params, queryParams) {
        var test = Tests.find({token: params.token}).fetch();

        if(test[0] === undefined)
            return BlazeLayout.render('app', {content: '404'});

        // if admin page
        if(params.admin && test[0].admin === params.admin) {
            var scores  = Scores.find({assessment: test[0].token}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch()
                , sum   = 0;

            Scores.forEach(s => sum += s.score);

            var mean = sum / scores.length;

            Session.set('scores.list', scores);
            Session.set('scores.sum', sum);
            Session.set('scores.mean', mean);
            return BlazeLayout.render('app', {content: 'admin'});
        }

        // take test
        Session.set('assessment', test[0]);
        BlazeLayout.render("app", {content: "take"});
    }
})
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, we need more info. One quick question is can you see your collection in your console? If so you simply have an error in your code.

Comment: No error. The data fetches properly if I already inserted something from the client, but not if I just try and fetch it in that session.